# is there a special term for using "very" in combination with adverby which can only be either/or

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Sometimes people use the word "very" in combination with adverbs which can only be either/or. for instance: "the floor is very wet". This may not be the best example, but the floor can either be *wet* or *not wet*. So the use of *very* doesn't add anything.

Is there a special term for this?

Comment: The floor can exhibit degrees of wetness. It  can be a little bit wet, mostly wet, partially wet, wet in spots, damp, under water, etc. And it certainly can be very wet. The state of the floor is a subjective interpretation, not a binary condition (unless you determine that the tiniest drop of water qualifies the floor to be viewed as wet).

Comment: A better example would be *"The table is very wooden."* But people don't usually say this. (On the other hand, an actor's performance can be *very wooden*.)

Comment: Thanks for your examples. How would you see it with *dynamic*? Can something be *very dynamic*?

Comment: Think about synonyms for _wet_ such as _damp_ and _soaked_. Clearly there's a scale of wetness where _damp_ would be slightly wet and _soaked_ would be very wet.

Comment: If you changed your example to "the floor is very hardwood," you'd have a good example of an either/or status (hardwood) needlessly modified by _very_. But you wouldn't have an example of something that people often say—so perhaps you should consider replacing your example with a sentence like "on the floor lay a very dead rat." There the phrase _very dead_ doesn't mean "more dead than a typical dead rat" but something like "very obviously dead" (owing, perhaps, to signals such as visible decay and a bad smell). I would be interested to know what the term for that use of _very_ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in a language forum, put laziness aside and capitalize the first word in a sentence. For it bothers us. OK?

"Wet" is a gradable notion, even if an object can or can't have it. Thus, I have no problem with seeing it associated with a qualifier like "very."

If you're not sure, try a search at Google Books (not vanilla Google)

["the floor is very wet"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22the%20floor%20is%20very%20wet%22)
About 123 results

E.g.

> Working for Victory: A Diary of Life in a Second World War ... - Page
>   200 Sue Bruley - 2011 -
>
> They would like to come to the Duppas Hill shelters, but they have no
>   bunks or rugs and **the floor is very wet**. So they sit out on the
>   hill all night and get very little rest.

See if those quotations are coming from authors having native-sounding names, whether the writing appeals to you in general, and make a decision whether you want to accept the application or not.

Now, about the term: I don't remember seeing one, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited my post to reflect your feedback on capitalization.